# Pushing to different branches in github from your local computer

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have an index.html file I have pushed to my main branch in github. Subsequently I want all my work to be in a different branch. On my local computer should I work in the same index.html or I should copy it onto a different file and work from there and push to the other branch. I have realised there are some conflicts on the local file when pushing to different branches. Sometimes getting back in time locally becomes a problem. I may not be explaining my problem well, but how do programmers handle files locally if they push to different branches on github.

I pushed to main branch, did changes on my file but then pushed to a different branch. I wanted to pick up from where I was working locally on my main branch but had problems doing so.

Comment: Do you understand what a branch is? It's just a name for a commit. If you don't like the name a commit has, change it. If a commit has no name and you wish it had one, give it one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear (it helps to show a concrete sequence of commands that results in a problem), but maybe this will help.

Let's say you are on the `main` branch locally:

```
$ git status
On branch main
```

You make some changes to `index.html` and push it to the `main` branch on GitHub:

```
vim index.html
...
git add index.html
git commit -m 'Moved navigation links to the left'
git push
```

Now you want to make some additional changes, but you don't want them on the `main` branch. First, create a new branch locally:

```
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
```

Make your changes, and push the new branch to GitHub:

```
vim index.html
...
git add index.html
git commit -m 'First step in a major resdesign'
git push -u origin HEAD
```

If you want to keep make changes to this branch, edit the file, `git add`, then `git push`.

If you want to go back to the `main` branch:

```
git checkout main
```